# “某些事实被别有用心的人断章取义和利用” in English?

Tags: translation

How do you say “某些事实被别有用心的人断章取义和利用” in English?

How is the following translation:

> Some facts have been （断章取义） and (taken advantage of) by some (别有用心) 的人？

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some facts were mistakenly taken advantage of by those with ulterior motives

Answer (score 2):

Some facts have been quoted out of context (断章取义) and taken advantage of by people with ulterior motives (别有用心).